# Accessing base class member variable address from derived class when both have the same variable name

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the address of a base class protected member variable.

Please help me understand what's wrong with this code:

```
class A 
{
protected:
  int m_;
};

class B : public A 
{
public:
  void Foo()
  {
    auto p1 = m_;                         // works but not what I want (B's member)
    auto p2 = &m_;                        // works but not the the address which I'm looking for (B's member)
    auto p3 = A::m_;                      // works but still not the address of the variable (A's member but not the address)
    auto p4 = &A::m_;                     // doesn't work -> int A::m_’ is protected within this context
    auto p5 = static_cast<A*>(this)->m_;  // doesn't work -> int A::m_’ is protected within this context
    auto p6 = &static_cast<A*>(this)->m_; // doesn't work -> int A::m_’ is protected within this context
  }
private:
    int m_;
};
```

Thanks

Gil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A problem you ran into is that `auto p4 = &A::m_;` declares a [pointer to data member](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_data_members). That is, the `auto` resolved itself to `int A::*`, not the `int *` you had intended. You can get the intended pointer by adding parentheses:

```
auto p4 = &(A::m_);
```

or if you want to make sure you get the type you intend:

```
int * p4 = &(A::m_);
```

Comment: Yeah... That's the answer which I was looking for... thanks

Answer (score 3):

`&static_cast<A*>(this)->m_` doesn't work because access to protected base class members is only allowed via a (reference or pointer to an) object of the same type as the class that the accessing function is a member (or friend) of.

That is, the following is not valid, even though `A` is a base of `B`

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    void Foo(const A& a)
    {
        auto i = a.m_; // Not valid
    }
};
```

See [[class.protected]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.protected).

`static_cast<A*>(this)` creates a pointer to `A`, which `B` cannot use to access `A`'s protected members.

The issue with `&A::m_` is that it's not taking a pointer to the `A::m_` member of the current object; it's actually forming a pointer-to-member.  i.e.

```
struct A
{
    int m_;
}

int main()
{
    auto foo = &A::m_;
    A a;
    a.*foo; // Accesses the m_ member of a
}
```

You can use the somewhat unusual syntax `&this->A::m_` to avoid hitting either of these pitfalls.

[Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28d3deb61a1fb305)